# Spot the error - Mixing: php data objects (fetch object), json, and jquery.post()

Tags: jquery, json, pdo

Can anyone better experienced then me, spot the issue here. 
I'm unable to debug it, my var_dumps don't seem to get any effect due to the use of jquery.post() so I believe.

I get nothing displayed. I was expecting to receive a li series filled with json encoded values.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id='data'></div>
<form action="">
  <input id="nomeInput" type="text" name="nomeInput" value="" autocomplete="false"/>
</form>
<ul id="listaDominios" style="display: none;">
</ul>
```

**The js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nomeInput').keypress(function(){
     $.post("testeBasico_1.php", {nomeInput : $('#nomeInput').val()}, function(resposta) {
        for (var x = 0, tamanhoDados = resposta.nomeDominio.length; x < tamanhoDados; x++){
           $('#listaDominios').show();
           $('#listaDominios').append('<li>'+resposta.nomeDominio[x]+'</li>');
        }

      }, "json");

  });//end of keypress;

});//end of document ready;
```

**The PHP**

```
public function listaDominios(DominioVo $dominioVo)
{
  try
  {
     $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT d.nomeDominio FROM dominio d WHERE d.nomeDominio LIKE ?");
     $stmt->bindValue(1,'%' . 'a' . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

     $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

       return $resultado;
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
      echo "Erro: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If the spot gets to be a difficult catch, how can I spot it. It's my first ajax experience, so I'm not comfortable with the debugging part. :s

**Suspicion:** (UPDATE)
I believe the issue is in the way I'm trying to iterate over the returned json.
Here's the echo format of the json_encoded:

```
[{"nomeDominio":"aaaa.ka"},{"nomeDominio":"agentesdeexecucao.ka"}]
```

Thanks a lot in advance,
MEM

Comment: Make a direct call to the PHP script first, and see whether it outputs anything.

Comment: I have access: "testeBasico_1.php" and var_dump the returned value from the database, and the corresponding json. both appear.

Comment: @MEM okay, then the next step is to output `resposta.nomeDominio.length` e.g. using `alert()` or `console.log` to see whether data comes through

Comment: I've updated my question where, I believe, I have this issue.

Comment: alert('length test: '+resposta.nomeDominio.length); I get no alert window. :(
If I do alert('hi'); on the same place, I do get the window. Shouldn't I receive a window with something, or empty, or null, but, still a window? :s

Comment: Ok, If I do the alert(resposta); I do get on the alert, the following: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] :s

Comment: And if I do alert(resposta.nomeDominio) I get undefined. SO. I'm not properly accessing nomeDominio apparently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the base of the object is an array you need to iterate over it at the root level, so your `for` loop should look like this:

```
$('#listaDominios').toggle(resposta.length > 0);
for (var x = 0; x < resposta.length; x++){
  $('#listaDominios').append('<li>'+resposta[x].nomeDominio+'</li>');
}
```

Or the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) route:

```
$('#listaDominios').toggle(resposta.length > 0);
$.each(resposta, function() {
  $('<li />', { text: this.nomeDominio }).appendTo('#listaDominios');
});
```

The important part is that `resposta.nomeDominio` isn't anything, since the root of the response is an Array, however `resposta.length` will get the length, so use that.  Also since the array is at the root and each object in it has a `nomeDominio` property, you want `resposta[x].nomeDominio` to go to the current index (to get the object), then call `.nomeDominio` to get the property. Or, use the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) route in which `this` refers to the current object, either way works.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Despite your nice explanation, I still have doubts that I hope you or anyone else can clear out. 
Why $('#listaDominios').toggle(resposta.length > 0); ?

+resposta[x].nomeDominio+ - Why resposta[x] ? I mean, I get that that X will be 1, 2 3 etc... right? But, how did you know from this: "[{"nomeDominio":"aaaa.ka"},{"nomeDominio":"agentesdeexecucao.ka"}]" that THAT will be the way to access each different "nomeDominio" key ?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: @MEM - I'm using `.toggle()` because it's a quick `.show()` or `.hide()` based on if there are any elements.  Also you use `resposta[x]` because `resposta` is the returned object, with is an Array...this is how your access an array :)

Comment: About the second question: Is it because, *naturally* the array as numeric key indexes? I thought the key on each of those key/value pars were "nomeDominio" and that, no number was associated to them...

Comment: @Nick Craver: So, if we have this json string: 
[{"nomeDominio":"aaaa.ka"},{"nomeDominio":"agentesdeexecucao.ka"}]
We have 1 ARRAY (noted by the []) that contains 2 OBJECTS noted by the {}, so what we are doing is iterate over an array of objects. 
And, each object of that array is an element of that array, so, in order to access those, we use a numerical reference. Precise?

Comment: @MEM - Correct, and once you have that object, via `array[index]` , you're just getting a property off of it.

Comment: Yeah! Nice! Thanks a lot! :) A very important lesson I learned today. I start to like arrays more. :D Again, thanks for your time and availability.

Comment: Ups... one last question:

Will not the each evaluate the length each time and, hence, be slower than if we do:

for (var x = 0, sizeData = resposta.length; x < sizeData; x++){
//we get the sizeData on the first iteration only, from there, always the same value, hence, faster way to access?